# Server troubles on Koding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, ip, server-side, koding

I've found Koding on the interwebs and I really dig it. In fact, I dig it so much, that I want to write my game server solely in Koding, hence it is a reliable app on the net, so I can work from anywhere anytime. But my problem is there, that when I want to try things from outside Koding (the client) I cannot connect to server. Unfortunately I haven't found the IP of my machine (I tried all the citruslee.kd.io variants I have [vm-0.], ifconfig -a adresses, but nothing really happened). The question is, how can I get the somewhat public IP of my VM?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. If you want to see your VM in action you can just access the URL [citruslee.kd.io](http://citruslee.kd.io) and if you run some other server (other then Apache, that comes preinstalled on all VMs) on your VM you can type the port after the URL. Keep in mind that your VM shuts down after ~15 mins. Hope I answered your question.

If you have any more questions you can always email us at support@koding.com

Comment: I want to connect to my ruby script on that VM, how can I achieve it? hence I know, that citruslee.kd.io is the stuff I needed, but when I want to connect to that computer, it ignores me full time :/